# I'm unableto install django

Tags: django, python-2.7, ubuntu-16.04

I tried install the django by using regular commands.but it is not installing

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo pip install django


or  

inside virtualenv

source bin/activate

then 

pip install django
```